# Drawing a wavy line gets clipped

Tags: android, path

In my app, I am drawing a wavy line to illustrate glissandos.

However, part of the 'wave' is getting clipped, as can be seen in the image.
[image]

Here is how I am creating the line.

1. Create a wavy 'stamp' path
2. Create a PathDashPathEffect object, passing in the 'stamp' path
3. Create a path for the line (moveTo and lineTo)
4. Set the paint style to STROKE
5. Set the wavy style with Paint.setPathEffect
6. Draw the line path

As Paint.setStrokeWidth will have no effect with a PathDashPathEffect object, I cannot use that to correct this problem.

Does anyone know why the start of my wavy line is getting clipped like this ?

More to the point, how to resolve this problem ?

---

Following Al's kind request, here is the code for drawing :

```
//----------------------------------------------------------
// creation of the wave stamp
m_StampPath = new Path();
m_StampPath.moveTo(0.0f, 6.86f * fScaling);
m_StampPath.cubicTo(10.29f * fScaling, -1.68f * fScaling, 
                    10.99f * fScaling, -1.40f * fScaling, 
                    17.29f * fScaling, 2.66f * fScaling);
m_StampPath.cubicTo(21.91f * fScaling, 6.86f * fScaling, 
                    24.08f * fScaling, 6.72f * fScaling, 
                    28.56f * fScaling, 2.66f * fScaling);
m_StampPath.lineTo(28.56f * fScaling, 4.76f * fScaling);
m_StampPath.cubicTo(17.78f * fScaling, 13.44f * fScaling, 
                    17.08f * fScaling, 12.25f * fScaling, 
                    11.90f * fScaling, 8.33f * fScaling);
m_StampPath.cubicTo(6.37f * fScaling, 4.41f * fScaling, 
                    4.62f * fScaling, 4.76f * fScaling, 
                    0.0f, 8.96f * fScaling);
m_StampPath.lineTo(0.0f, 6.86f * fScaling);

fStampOffset = 23.5f * fScaling;
m_fTextOffset = -8.96f * fScaling;
m_WavyLine = new PathDashPathEffect(m_StampPath, fStampOffset, 0.0f, PathDashPathEffect.Style.MORPH);

//--------------------------------------------------------
// drawing the line
m_GlissandoPath = new Path();
m_GlissandoPath.moveTo(m_ptStart.x, m_ptStart.y);
m_GlissandoPath.lineTo(m_ptEnd.x, m_ptEnd.y);

oldStyle = pt.getStyle();
pt.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
cv.drawPath(m_GlissandoPath, pt);

// remove the path effect
pt.setPathEffect(null);
```

Comment: You should show the code that does the drawing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is what I have done to fix this problem.

It would appear that there is a bug in pathdashpatheffect in that it will render correctly if the "line" goes from top left to bottom right.

However, it will clip if the line goes up from bottom left to top right.

The solution to this problem is to set a stroke width which corresponds to the height of the stamp.

All works correctly now.

This could be an addition to official Google documentation ... perhaps.